# bug while trying to create a function from other functions in python

Tags: python, function, import, calculator

I have been trying to create a calculator and i had for practical reasons i tried to import functions from a separate python file. It works at some extent but it breaks when it tries to do the calculations. The bug is is that the add is not defined but i did defined it while importing the function. Here is the code:

```
class Calculator(object):

import a10 as add
import d10 as div
import m10 as mult
import s10 as sub

def choice(self):
    print("A. Addition\l B. Substraction\l C. Division\l D. Multiplication")
    xn = input("What do you want to do? ")
    if xn == "a":
        addition = add.addition
        x = self.addition()
        self.x = x
        return x
    elif xn == "b":
        subtraction = sub.subtraction
        z = self.subtraction()
        self.z = z
        return z
    elif xn == "c":
        division = div.division
        y = self.division()
        self.y = y
        return y
    elif xn == 'd':
        Multiplication = mult.multiplication
        v = self.Multiplication()
        self.v = v
        return v


objcalc = Calculator()
print(objcalc.choice())
```

Here is the a10

```
def addition(self):
try:
    n = int(input("enter number: "))  
    n_for_add = int(input("What do you want to add on " + str(n) + " ? "))       
except ValueError: 
    print("you must enter an integer!") 
n_from_add = n + n_for_add
print(str(n) + " plus " + str(n_for_add) + " equals to " + str(n_from_add))
```

s10

```
def subtraction(self):
    try:
        nu = int(input("enter number: "))
        nu_for_sub = int(input("What do you want to take off " + str(nu) + " ? "))
    except ValueError:
        print("you must enter an integer!")
    nu_from_sub = nu - nu_for_sub
    print(str(nu) + " minus " + str(nu_for_sub) + " equals to " + str(nu_from_sub))
```

m10

```
def Multiplication(self):
    try:
        numb = int(input("enter number: "))
        numb_for_multi = int(input("What do you want to multiply " + str(numb) + " on? "))
    except ValueError:
        print("you must enter an integer!")
    numb_from_multi = numb * numb_for_multi
    print(str(numb) + " multiplied by  " + str(numb_for_multi) + " equals to " + str(numb_from_multi))
```

d10

```
def division(self):
    try:
        num = int(input("enter number: "))
        num_for_div = int(input("What do you want to divide " + str(num) + " off? "))
    except ValueError:
        print("you must enter an integer!")
    num_from_div = num / num_for_div
    print(str(num) + " divided by " + str(num_for_div) + " equals to " + str(num_from_div))
```

Comment: `addition` isn't indented properly.

Comment: your class also isn't indented properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `if` statements, like this:

```
if xn == "a":
    addition = add.addition
    x = self.addition()
    self.x = x
    return x
```

`addition` is created as a variable local to the function `choice`, but you're then setting `x` to be `self.addition()`, which isn't defined.

If you mean to write `x = add.addition()` then be warned that your `addition` function doesn't return anything, it just prints out a value. The same for the other functions - none of them return anything. So `self.addition` is not defined, and `x` will be a `NoneType` object

Your `addition`, `subtraction` and other functions also take `self` as an argument, when they're not methods in a class, so this doesn't make much sense.